# User Edit Resource not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have a user resource with is linked in the `users` table.

My Route:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

UserController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('user.edit')->with(array('user'=>$user));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('user/'.$id.'/edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

And my View

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="flash-message">
        @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
          @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
          <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }}</p>
          @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{$user->name}}" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="id_number" id="id_number" value="{{$user->id_number}}" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

So with this setup I expect that when click the submit button on my page it will go in the `update()` function just like my other resource. But problem is when I click submit it will direct me to

```
http://localhost/hrs/public/user/1
```

and a white blank page with no errors what so ever. So it means it's going to my `update` function? I am following same pattern with my other resource and this is the only one not working.

Comment: Maybe You are just not getting validation error? That url is proper path for `update` method, so I think that everything works just fine. Try to put `dd('here')` in your `update` method. I bet You will see `here` :)

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys Thanks for the suggestion. I finally know whats going on. haha the request goes after the validator fails. Since I don't have the else part it will do nothing haha

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong web server configuration. You should point your web server (usually Apache or nginx) to a `public` directory of your Laravel project. After that restart web server.

For example for Apache correct configuration will be something like this:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrs/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrs/public">
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help but there's nothing wrong with my public diretory as i am able to login the system and everything. Problem is the update method but I fixed it now

Comment: When Laravel builds url with a public in it, that means you have wrong configuration. You will catch a lot of similar errors if you'll not fix this.

Comment: It's ok if I have the public in url because I am in Dev Stage, I am removing the public in the production. I understand using virtual host. Anyways my problem in my question is just a i forgot to add the 'else' part of my code and has nothing to do with URL's or Direcotry :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I don't have the `else` part of the validation. as that is where the event goes to. Since I don't have it, it will do nothing.

```
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('user/'.$id.'/edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        dd($rules);
    }
```